# Given characteristic polynomial of $T$, need find characteristic polynomial of $T^3$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}^2 $ be a linear transformation with characteristic polynomial $x^2+2x-3$. Find the characteristic polynomial of $T^3$.

How to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm guessing you mean $T: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$. Do you know the relation between the eigenvalues of $T$ and $T^3$?

Comment: Yes, You are correct!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT: If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $\operatorname{T}$ then $\lambda^n$ is an eigenvalue of $\operatorname{T}^n$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the transformation matrix of $T$ is symmetric with$\lambda=1,-3$. Hence the eigenvalues of the transformation matrix of $T^3$ are $1,-27$. So the characteristic equation is $$(x-1)(x+27)=0$$